# error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, static

I am having problem with this code:

```
package javaapplication16;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
public class JavaApplication16 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewJFrame n = new NewJFrame();
        n.setVisible(true);
        InputStream is;
        is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("samp.wav");
        try {
            AudioStream audioStream;
            audioStream = new AudioStream(is);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

It is saying that

```
error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("samp.wav");
```

If I make the InputStream variable static then its telling me illegal start of expression. I have also removed the `this` keyword. Still the problem is not solving. How can fix it?

Comment: What would `this` be without an instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just avoid the problem, like so:

```
JavaApplication16.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("samp.wav");
```

Comment: owao! ! ! the error has gone. Now I can understand it. But when I run the program its giving me another exception error:
`java.lang.NullPointerException`
why?

Comment: @Tushar I recommend you accept one of these answers to finish this question.  Then submit the new problem as a new question.

Comment: @Tushar: probably it can't find the wav file. getResourceAsStream returns null if the file isn't present. also: 1) I agree with Guido's comment, 2) asking people to explain an exception without showing them a stacktrace is unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

you cant use `this keyword` inside a static method. `this` keyword can only be used
Within an instance method or a constructor. `this` is a reference to the current object.

try:

```
    is = YourClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("samp.wav");
```

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, use a class literal instead:

```
    is = JavaApplication16.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("samp.wav");
```