# Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context for eeyore?

Tags: java

I have a class called `ChristopherRobin` (sub class of `HundredAcreWoodsCharacter`) in which there is a method called `FindTail()`.

In another class, `Eeyore` (sub class of `HundredAcreWoodsCharacter` also), I want to try and use the method `FindTail()` from `ChristopherRobin`. I'm not sure how to do this. I tried

```
    if (ChristopherRobin.hasTail())
```

but that gives me the error:

```
non-static method hasTail() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

If anyone could help it would be great, thanks.

Also, if it's worth mentioning that this is being done in `GridWorld` (from the AP Computer Science case study). `HundredAcreWoodsCharacter` is a subclass of `Critter`.

Comment: You're calling the non-static method *on the class*, something that can't be done. You need to first create a ChristopherRobin object and then call the method on the object.

Comment: You should probably post your code for ChristopherRobin and HundredAcreWoods.

Comment: Google found hundreds of items explaining this error message. Have you even tried to google it???

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593548/error-non-static-variable-this-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the non-static method *on the class*, something that can't be done. You need to first create a ChristopherRobin object and then call the method on the object.

```
// create the ChristopherRobin object and put in the christopherRobin variable
ChristopherRobin christopherRobin = new ChristopherRobin();

// now call the method on the *object* held by the variable
if (christopherRobin.hasTail()) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: For this project, we had to make a runner class in which one of each character is created, so would your suggestion still work?

Comment: Although this will fix the compilation error, it might not be the best solution. If it was so simple, the method hasTail() should probably be a static method. The christopherRobin object should in fact probably passed as argument to the method being called, or to the constructor.

Comment: In GridWorld, Critters are stored in a collection and processed by the framework. hasTail probably only needs to be called by this Critter itself.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to override the act() or, since this is a subclass of Critter, override one of the methods that act() calls. For instance, if having a tail affects how this Critter can move, then you would override `getMoveLocations()`  Here's an example of how hasTail could be used:

```
//Critters with tails can only move forward. 
public ArrayList<Location> getMoveLocations() {
   if(this.hasTail()) {
      ArrayList<Location> listOfOne = new ArrayList<Location>();
      listOfOne.add(getLocation.getAdjacentLocation(this.getDirection()) );
      return listOfOne;
   }
   else
      return super.getMoveLocations();
}
```